# Using AsyncItemWriter with CompositeItemWriter

Tags: spring-batch, compositeitemwriter

Can `AsyncItemWriter` be used with `CompositeItemWriter`?

From the source code:

- `public class CompositeItemWriter<T> implements ItemStreamWriter<T>, InitializingBean`
- `public interface ItemStreamWriter<T> extends ItemStream, ItemWriter<T>`
- `public class AsyncItemWriter<T> implements ItemStreamWriter<Future<T>>, InitializingBean`

The below code snippet to create a CompositeItemWriter using two AsyncItemWriter objects causes a compilation issue at the line - `compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(itemWriterList);` with the below error message. What am I missing here?

> Required type: List<ItemWriter<? super Employee>>
>
> Provided: List<AsyncItemWriter>

```
    @Bean
    public AsyncItemWriter<Employee> asyncEmployeeJsonWriter() {
        AsyncItemWriter<Employee> asyncItemJsonWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
        asyncItemJsonWriter.setDelegate(empJsonWriter);
        return asyncItemJsonWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncItemWriter<Employee> asyncEmployeeCsvWriter() {
        AsyncItemWriter<Employee> asyncItemCsvWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
        asyncItemCsvWriter.setDelegate(empCsvWriter);
        return asyncItemCsvWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CompositeItemWriter<Employee> compositeItemWriter() {
        List<AsyncItemWriter<Employee>> itemWriterList = new ArrayList<>();
        itemWriterList.add(asyncEmployeeJsonWriter());
        itemWriterList.add(asyncEmployeeCsvWriter());
        CompositeItemWriter<Employee> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter();
        compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(itemWriterList);
        return compositeItemWriter;
    }
```

Both `empJsonWriter` and `empCsvWriter` implement `ItemWriter`.

Dependency versions:

- spring-batch-integration-4.3.4.jar
- spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar
- spring-boot-starter-batch:jar - 2.4.13
- javax.batch-api:jar - 1.0

**P.S.**

- There is a related question about AsyncItemWriter with ClassifierCompositeItemWriter - [ClassifierCompositeItemWriter with AsyncItemWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61260916/classifiercompositeitemwriter-with-asyncitemwriter) but I need a code example to use `AsyncItemWriter` with `CompositeItemWriter`.
- The issue here - [Issue in AsyncItemWriter with Spring Batch 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76005840/issue-in-asyncitemwriter-with-spring-batch-5) is about Spring Boot 3 and Spring Batch 5.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience, but I solved it by changing it to the structure below.

Instead of delegating the AsyncItemWriter to the CompositeItemWriter, delegate the ItemWriters(in your code, `empJsonWriter` and `empCsvWriter`) to the CompositeItemWriter first, and delegate this CompositeItemWriter to the AsyncItemWriter.

So, maybe like this,

```
@Bean
public AsyncItemWriter<Employee> asyncEmployeeWriter() {
    AsyncItemWriter<Employee> asyncItemWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
    asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(compositeItemWriter());
    return asyncItemWriter;
}

@Bean
public CompositeItemWriter<Employee> compositeItemWriter() {
    List<ItemWriter<Employee>> itemWriterList = new ArrayList<>();
    itemWriterList.add(employeeJsonWriter());
    itemWriterList.add(employeeCsvWriter());
    CompositeItemWriter<Employee> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter();
    compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(itemWriterList);
    return compositeItemWriter;
}
```

It works to me. :)